# Sorting a list of names lexographically

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, big-o

Say you are given a list of names, S = {s1, s2 ... sn} and you want to sort them lexicographically.

How would you guarantee that the running time of the sort is O(the total sum of the lengths of all the words)?

Any useful techniques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution would be to use [MSD radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Most_significant_digit_radix_sorts), assuming a constant-size alphabet. Replace "digit" by "character" while reading the algorithm description. You will also need to throw out strings that are smaller than *i* if you are currently processing the position *i*, otherwise you won't get the desired runtime.

Comment: Isn't this going to take O(n*d) time? Here d is the length of the longest word.

Comment: @hyde no, not if you only process every string s only up to recursion depth |s|. That's why I mentioned that you need to throw stop processing strings if they "run out".